# side effects of encoding c style strings in base 64

Tags: c

My application normally logs binary messages to a file. It encodes the binary message in base64 and stores some string based metadata with each message to make it searchable. 
Now, we would like to log messages which are plain C style strings. Is there any side effect/gotchas if the c-style strings can be base 64 encoded?

Comment: No. By right, even binary data can be encoded in base 64, so there will be no difference with C-style string.

Comment: Just curious why you bother to B64 encode a string... One side effect is that it will take up more space; how much depends on the input size.

Comment: @Ioan the app already encodes binary into base64. So if it can encode simple c style strings, no changes in algo is required, else , i would have to detect if incomming message has payload of type binary vs string.